# Cisco privilege level access without a password. How can I prevent this?

Tags: cisco

At work there is a new cisco device that was recently installed. There are configs for users to modify interfaces at priv 10, but nothing defined for any other priv levels. There is an `enable level 10 secret` and an `enable secret`. When anyone logs in and runs `en 10` they are prompted for a password. When they run `en` they are prompted for a password, however they can run `en 11` and any other number up to 14 without a password and are given access to all of the commands that priv 10 has access to. This doesn't seem right to me. Can any point me in the right direction to give people a kick back and log the failed attempt if they attempt access to priv 11 on up? Or am I just going to have to set a password for all of those priv levels?

Comment: What kind of "device"? Sounds like an ASA (PixOS). Cisco has made 3 different device OSes and they all have subtle differences, like security.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to force everybody to use a password, issue `no enable 10` in config mode.

Refer to http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/security/configuration/guide/scfpass.html#wp1001016 for details on how to protect privileged EXEC commands.

Comment: It doesn't accept `no enable 10` in the configuration terminal.

Comment: I found what I needed. The guys that did the install didn't put any authorization statements. I just did `aaa authorization exec default local` then took away enable from anyone under priv 11 with `privilege exec level 11 enable` Now no one under level 11 can elevate them selves, and everyone starts out at their priv, removing the need for the enable set. Thanks for taking a look and trying, adaptr! I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: Oh well, nobody like Cisco for being inconsistent!